# java script function returned value from array by parent id

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array 
`var sub_type=[[]];`
every element in this array is row that include  3 value (id,name,parent_id)
for example-

```
row1 [1,"mobile",0]
row2 [2,"samsung",1]
row3 [3,"sony",1]
row4 [4,"S4",2]
row5 [5,"S5",2]
row6 [6,"C2",3]
row7 [7,"Z3",3]
```

how can i build a function that returned all (childs and parents) for an id like that:

```
function get_parent_child(some_id){code here}
```

if i enter id=2 it return parent=1 child=4,5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var mainArray = [[1, "test", 0],
                [2, "test1", 1],
                [3, "test2", 1],
                [4, "test3", 2],
                [5, "test4", 2]];

var matchedChilds = getChilds(mainArray, 1);
console.log(matchedChilds);

function getChilds(arr, id){
  var childs = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if(arr[i][0] == id || arr[i][2] == id){
      childs.push(arr[i]);
    }
  }
  return childs;
}
```

If the arrays keeps staying like this (Id, Name, ParentId) you can just walk through the array and get the childs. This will create a new array with the childs you want by the parentId.

One possible way to do this.

Comment: i want  the parent also, childs not enough to me

Comment: You'll get the parent with the code above, just not sorted. Check the output. First item in my example is the parent.. remaining two are the childs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Array filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

**see the bellow Snippet**

```js
var sub_type = [
  [1, "mobile", 0],
  [2, "samsung", 1],
  [3, "sony", 1],
  [4, "S4", 2],
  [5, "S5", 2],
  [6, "C2", 3],
  [7, "Z3", 3]
];



function get_parent_child(some_id) {
  var myElement = sub_type.find(function(el) {
    return el[0] == some_id;
  });
  return sub_type.filter(function(el) {
    return (el[0] == myElement[2] || el[2] == myElement[0]);
  })
}

console.log(get_parent_child(2));
```

Comment: it is returned just child, i want to return parent also